# Integer to String conversion?

Tags: java, string, integer

I have a problem with Integer.toString conversion. This code outputs "ololo". Why? And how can I convert integer to string right?

```
 String str1= "1";
 String str2=Integer.toString(1);
 if (str1!=str2)Log.d("myLogs","ololo");
```

Comment: You must compare `String`s using `equals` method, not `==` nor `!=`.

Comment: Search for `String comparison Java`, you will get a lot of hits.

Comment: Why do you take toString() of the Integer?? Just use `String str2= 1 + "";`

Comment: Or if you think it's not a good practice, use `String.valueOf(1);` And do NOT compare Strings with == or !=. Use `if(string1.equals(string2)){}`

Comment: @GnomezGrave: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `Integer.toString()`.

Comment: I meant, the other way is the easy way.. or the lazy way. :)

Answer (score 2):

You must compare `String`s using `equals` method, not `==` nor `!=` operators since they will compare the `String` object references.

```
if (!str1.equals(str2)) {
    Log.d("myLogs","ololo");
}
```

Note that when you use `Integer#toString` you're creating a new `String` that is not in the `String` JVM pool, thus getting the error described.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison must be done with equals.
`if (!str1.equals(str2))...`

When you use `!=` you get reference equality (inequality)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`String.valueOf(1);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) to change Integer to String.

Answer (score 0):

use `!str1.equals(str2)` instead.

You shouldn't use `==` or `!=` for String